# About Polymer and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, polymer

If I would like to convert  Bootstrap components into polymer, To my understanding all jQuery needs to be converted to javascript and every components will include the bootstrap stylesheet. any better way of refactoring? Polymer feels like the end of bootstrap and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted my question on polymer Google+ page and +Herman Willems answered my question. In case anyone willing to port Bootstrap to Polymer, here are the links: 
http://news.dartlang.org/2013/03/bootstrap-widgets-ported-to-web.html
https://github.com/MikeCostello/bootstrap-web-components

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is dependent on jQuery, which has a very different design philosophy from Polymer. Polymer components aim to be lightweight and fast by embedding functionality in the component, while jQuery is all about making it easy to find elements and add events for HTML content that you already have.

As they're at cross purposes downloading both jQuery and Polymer and trying to use both is probably not the best idea.

Most Bootstrap components work by looking for attributes on the tag and adding functionality when they're found, for instance `data-toggle="dropdown"`.

If you switch from that pattern to Polymer you'll get drastically different code, so: `<bootstrap-dropdown>content</bootstrap-dropdown>` custom elements instead of `<button id="id" data-toggle="dropdown"></button><div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dd">content</div>` or `$('selector').dropdown()`.

Basically, with jQuery and Bootstrap JS you're adding an application's worth of framework to download (and parse, 85k of JS for jQuery takes a *lot* longer to parse on an average phone) and miss all the advantages of Polymer. With Bootstrap components ported to Polymer you have to write for the whole new component style - you end up writing a Polymer app or component from scratch.

What may be worth porting is the styles - Polymer components with Bootstrap design language rather than Material Design. In some cases you may just be able to use custom styles and themes for existing components.

What I've also found worth keeping is the 12 column grid, so [I've ported that to a Polymer component](https://github.com/KeithHenry/bootstrap-grid).